# How to "mark as merged" in TFS?

Tags: tfs

How can I perform the equivalent of a "mark as merged" operation?

I know about command "tf.exe" merge" with key "/discard", but it cannot be used by "big" team.

The operation needs for next scenario:

- Version 1 in Production
- Version 2 (created from Version 1) in Development
- Found and fixed bug in Version 1
- Sometimes the bug doesn't exists in Version 2 (because other fix, redesign, etc.). In the case, I don't want to merge from Version 1 to Version 2. I want only "mark as merged".

So, how can I support the process ("mark as merged") in TFS?
Svn (TortoiseSVN), for example, has simple "check-box" (Only record the merge) in simple wizard.

Comment: What I have always done is to merge from "Version 1" to "Version 2", then, in resolving the merge conflict, take the "Version 2" side.

Comment: BTW, I have edited your question and title to focus more on how you can do the equivalent. Your question as written could not be answered except by someone on the TFS team.

Comment: But when I have not conflicts, but in any case, I don't need the changeset?

Comment: You may not need it, but then, where's the harm in keeping the changeset as an indication that the merge took place? In particular, remember that TFS can track a changeset across branches.